# Mac continuously wakes up with unidentified reason

Tags: sleep-wake

I have MacBook Air 2013, Mavericks installed.

I recognized that my mac is a little bit warm. Thus I looked into Console

```
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:23.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110987.511839: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep 
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:23.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: hibernate image path: /var/vm/sleepimage
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: efi pagecount 63
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 1) start 0xffffff80e49e5000, 0xffffff80e4a25000
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 365 ms
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: pages 848454, wire 182600, act 237393, inact 401258, cleaned 0 spec 23, zf 18, throt 0, compr 19920, xpmapped 582514
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: could discard act 2164 inact 342 purgeable 298 spec 4438 cleaned 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall preflight pageCount 182600 est comp 50 setfile 398107400 min 1073741824
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: [0xce0387000, 0x19000000]
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: [0xd92a6d000, 0x27000000]
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: [0x0, 0x0]
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: kern_open_file_for_direct_io(0) took 6 ms
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: Opened file /var/vm/sleepimage, size 1073741824, partition base 0x0, maxio 2000000 ssd 1
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: hibernate image major 1, minor 0, blocksize 4096, pollers 5
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:24.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80248dd200>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80248dd200>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: vm_compressor_flush - starting
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: vm_compressor_flush completed - took 920 msecs
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_flush_memory: buffer_cache_gc freed up 410 wired pages
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_alloc_pages act 183714, inact 401599, anon 150, throt 0, spec 4470, wire 196933, wireinit 139519
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_setup(0) took 1711 ms
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 00:26:66:c4:80:fc
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103116: scanparams:
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103120:   flags 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103122:   active_time 0, passive_time 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103125:   scan_start_delay 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103128:   scan_cycle_idle_rest_time 0, scan_cycle_idle_rest_time_multiplier 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103131:   max_scan_cycles 0, max_rest_time 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103134: Scan Channels (0): None
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103136: SSID (0): None
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103139: SSID count = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110990.103142: wl0: leaveModulePoweredForOffloads: Wi-Fi will turn off.
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en0 en0 Link DOWN virtIf = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:27.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::waitForOk2Go2Sx - retries = 2
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall(preflight 0) start 0xffffff80e49e5000, 0xffffff80e4a25000
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_teardown started
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_teardown: wired_pages 197418, free_pages 1301445, active_pages 181244, inactive_pages 401257, speculative_pages 13, cleaned_pages 0, compressor_pages 80
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_teardown_pmap_structs done: last_valid_compact_indx 182648
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_teardown: mark_as_unneeded_pages 4096, 21879, 18520
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_teardown completed - discarded 44495
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall time: 631 ms
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: pages 727611, wire 137748, act 181244, inact 401257, cleaned 0 spec 13, zf 0, throt 0, compr 80, xpmapped 582514
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: did discard act 2172 inact 342 purgeable 298 spec 4457 cleaned 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_page_list_setall found pageCount 720342
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen, ml_get_interrupts_enabled 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: IOHibernatePollerOpen(0)
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: encryptStart 14010
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: bitmap_size 0x3f908, previewSize 0x8984a8, writing 717810 pages @ 0x8ebdc0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: encryptEnd 6b01e00
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: image1Size 0xc6dc000, encryptStart1 0x14010, End1 0x6b01e00
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: encryptStart c6dc000
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: PMStats: Hibernate write took 4616 ms
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: all time: 4616 ms, comp bytes: 1523429376 time: 1679 ms 865 Mb/s, crypt bytes: 977346032 time: 2317 ms 402 Mb/s, 
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: image 0 (0%), uncompressed 1523425280 (371930), compressed 1060983680 (69%), sum1 5feda202, sum2 2b52bf9e
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: zeroPageCount 21073, wiredPagesEncrypted 74759, wiredPagesClear 60589, dirtyPagesEncrypted 236583
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(e00002e8)
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: sleep
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_rebuild started
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_rebuild_pmap_structs done: last_valid_compact_indx 182648
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: hibernate_rebuild completed - took 109 msecs
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: ?
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleHSSPIController::HandleMessage Device Wake by Host
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.261 hidd[72]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80248dd200>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80248dd200>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0100 [x]
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110997.359426: si_survive_perst_war: bar0win before 18003000, bar0win after 18001000
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.615 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Inactive
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.618 configd[18]: network changed: v4(en0-:192.168.0.29) DNS- Proxy-
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 110997.591101: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:34.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 111000.304746: MacAuthEvent en0   Auth result for: 00:26:66:c4:80:fc  MAC AUTH succeeded
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en0 en0 Link UP virtIf = 0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Up on en0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 00:26:66:c4:80:fc
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en0
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.539 configd[18]: network changed: DNS* Proxy
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.542 mDNSResponder[64]: mDNS_RegisterInterface: Frequent transitions for interface en0 (192.168.0.29)
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.548 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [CNInfoNetworkActive:1655] en0: SSID 'monet2.4G' making interface primary (cache indicates network not captive)
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.548 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Evaluating
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.552 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: en0: Not probing 'monet2.4G' (cache indicates not captive)
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.553 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.555 configd[18]: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.0.29) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:37.000 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:39.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
2013. 10. 25. PM 9:36:39.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
```

These logs are repeated again and again with time interval about a couple of minutes.

I searched some articles and found that I can see why Mac wakes up by looking into `Wake reason.` But in my case, the reason is **Question mark (?)**

What should I do right now?

Is there any way to see which factor wakes mac up?

Comment: I have this identical issue, I had my laptop lid closed overnight, came down and it was warm with the same errors. It seems to be continually rewriting the hibernate file, too, which scares me a little as it's going to have been thrashing my SSD. Hardware is 2013 MBPR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with my MacBook Air Haswell and OS X 10.9. You can add a workaround for this by disabling standby/hibernation.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo pmset -a standby 0
```

This will disable hibernation. To activate it again type:

```
sudo pmset -a standby 1
```

If you look at the log closely, the "sleep loop" starts right after going into deep sleep (hibernation) after 3 hours in energy saving mode. You will lose 2-3% battery over night but still better than a sleep loop.

If you have Avast! Antivirus installed, I would try uninstalling it first, this fixed the issue on my Mac.